# Programatically parsing web pages (with login/ssl)

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, html-parsing

I want to programmatically parse some Web pages on sites that do not have a publicly available API.

For example check if my grades are ready at the university.

Has anyone done anything like this and gotten to a usable solution? I'm probably looking for a library written in python or something similar, right?

Also note that some of these sites need login and/or ssl. How would you suggest to handle that?

Comment: Python has many packages for web scraping. [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) is very well documented with a official tutorial and large user base.
Scrapy supports [logging in](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) and there's an fairly active community here on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using urllib or urllib2, it allows you to send/receive requests and gives you HTML objects you can easily parse.

```
import urllib
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080/'}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
f = opener.open("http://www.python.org")
f.read()
```

More information on how to use it : https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: i know urllib.... I want something that helps me to parse the data, not just give me raw html...